# raise OSError('could not get source code') Unexpected exception formatting exception. Falling back to standard exception PROBLEM

Tags: visual-studio-code

im practicing on this Dataset and it was working all fine until it didnt , i was trying to turn theses strings into Ints and and floats it worked the first time but then i took a break came back to my machine and it all was off , i was using python 3.9 , later i upgraded it to the latest 3.9.12 didn't do anything. thanks in advance .

i tried to uninstall python and pandas and upgraded to the latest version but didnt do much  , my  python_enviroment its working just fine .

Comment: Hey @Alex-Martinez , were you able to sort this out? I'm running into a similar error when trying to parse dates. with pandas (first few dataframes work, but some don't)